# Git pull requests on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

Having a weird issue with bitbucket at the moment.

Im making pull requests for my branches to the dev who maintains the main repo that i forked off. And every time, on my end, the pull request seems to send the branch and commits in that branch perfectly, but when the dev looks at the pull request in order to merge or decline, it seems as though bitbucket is also adding the commits from the last merged branch in with the pull request.

Here is an exmple pull request (this is what the dev sees on his end)

[image: pull request]

So the first 2 files listed are the ones that i committed to the branch that i sent the pull request for. The last file is from a totally different branch and commit which i have already sent a pull request for and has been merged in.

To make this even weird as a test myself and the dev decided to merge one of the iffy pull requests into the main repo. When merged we saw in terminal that the files from the commit that WERE supposed to be in the pull request were the only ones merged in.

So basically these files are showing in the pull request in bitbucket, but im not sending them with the pull request of my branch and theyre also not being merged when the dev merges the pull request with the main repo.

Any ideas on whats happening here, got us pretty stumped.

Cheers

Comment: Did you closed the old feature branch, and start it again off his new master/dev branch? If you dont do that, your local branch still was generated from that old master/dev he has, and yes, have all your history in it. Does it make sense? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem lies in your local repository.

Let's say that you have two files on the master branch: A and B

You create your feature branch with `git checkout -b feature-a`.  You're now working in the **feature-a** branch. You hack away on file A, commit and push it, and then submit a pull request for it.  Your pull request is accepted so you delete your branch **feature-a** with `git branch -d feature-a`.  Now you're back on **master**.  You decide to work on feature-b so you `git checkout -b feature-b`.  This is where your problem is.

When you went back to **master** and created a new branch based off of it, if you haven't pulled in the changes with `git pull origin` then your **master** branch and therefore your **feature-b** branch won't know about your changes in **feature-a**.

To solve your issue, make sure that before you create any new feature branches you run `git pull` on your **master** branch.